# Why can't I connect to my mssql database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've done so much research trying to get my PHP code hosted on IIS to connect to my MSSQL database. I just can't seem to figure out the issue. Has anyone come across this before?

```
<?php

$serverName = 'AEGIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo=array('Database'=>'tttb_db');

$con = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($con){
    echo 'Connection established<br />';
}
else {
    echo 'Connection failed<br />';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}

?>
```

Update, we have a new error:

> Connection failed
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "tttb_db" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "tttb_db" requested by the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "tttb_db" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "tttb_db" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )

Our SQL server is using Windows Authentication and our server name is `AEGIS-PC\SQLEXPRESS` with the user name and password blocks are greyed out. I can not think of reason our login would be failing. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Can you prove that your IIS server is running the code as PHP at all?  Try creating a page that has only `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and make sure the info screen is being displayed.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: Have you checked PHP is working on your machine, and that you have the necessary PHP extensions to connect to SQL Server? What version of PHP are you running? Do a `phpinfo();` in your code to have a look at extensions.

Comment: I have installed PHP. I can get simple variables to display on the screen so I know IIS is running PHP. The script seems to break when it gets to the database portion.

Comment: php phpinfo(); is displaying

Comment: @halfer I have installed Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server.
Put the correct files into the PHP ext folder and liked them in the php.ini extension list

[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll

Comment: @Maxiumus2012 no errors......

Comment: Your second example doesn't return the `die()` statement?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No sir. This has been really frustrating

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Sorry guys, decently new to this. I now have updated the question with my new found information

Comment: what about using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

Comment: `http://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-php/` is a tutorial for using Microsoft Web Platform Installer to gather and deploy everything you need.

Comment: could you have a mismatch between 32/64 bitness?

Comment: Please use code formatting instead of using a quote

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that could cause such problems:

1.) Your modules aren't loaded because its VC9 instead if VC11. Check which compiler version your system use and install the correct driver.

2.) Check your PHP Version and use the correct driver for your PHP-Version your can check that in your `phpinfo()`.

3.) Don't forget to install the MSSQL Native Client otherwise you can't connect to your database that is the problem what I have every time.

Your code looks good and if your get the error message that `sqlsrv_connect` isn't found that is a signal that the module is not loaded.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: We have gotten our modules to load! Now we have a new error

Comment: Updated the original question

Answer (score 3):

It's just a simple solution I found to mine. checkout http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/

it's just a few steps.

1. Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties
2. In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.

this should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a service account for the 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR' system account to let IIS access the database.

This is the key part of the error string:

```
 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'
```

When someone hits the website and the php script tries to access the SQL Server, it does it using IIS's system account, not the user on the website's account. You can have IIS use windows authentication for the DB request. See below for enabling Windows Authentication with IIS:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Fair warning, it only works if the user hitting the web page is in the same AD domain as the web server.

Be careful what privileges you assign to the IIS system account, if you go that route at all.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to SQL Server >> Security >> Logins and right click on NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE and select Properties
2-  In newly opened screen of Login Properties, go to the “User Mapping” tab. Then, on the “User Mapping” tab, select the desired database – especially the database for which this error message is displayed. On the lower screen, check the role db_owner. Click OK.