# Unable to connect to my mssql database using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I see that another user had a similar question: [Why can't I connect to my mssql database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635901/why-cant-i-connect-to-my-mssql-database-using-php)

I am getting identical errors.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userName'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userName'.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42000
            [SQLSTATE] => 42000
            [1] => 4060
            [code] => 4060
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DBname" requested by the login. The login failed.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DBname" requested by the login. The login failed.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userName'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'userName'.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 42000
            [SQLSTATE] => 42000
            [1] => 4060
            [code] => 4060
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DBname" requested by the login. The login failed.
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DBname" requested by the login. The login failed.
        )

)
```

I've succeeded in displaying `phpinfo()` for my page.

- Looks like I'm running MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) (not sure how to update to 11 - or if I even need to).
- PHP version: 5.3.28 (not sure where to look in phpinfo for driver information).
- Not sure how to check that MSSQL Native Client is installed.

I'm unable to find my php.ini file. It's supposedly located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini` but I don't see it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message I assume that the connection works but your credentials don't. Is it really correct to use *userName* as the username and *DBname* as the db name. Looks like you have a copy/paste problem there.

Regarding the ini file: You should see it in the phpinfo output, search for *Loaded Configuration File*.

Comment: @laraw1n Thank you for your prompt response. I actually intended to use ambiguous username/dbname information (just seems a bit more secure). You were right about the credentials, my database did not have the user / pwd given permission. After that was added, voila!

Also, regarding the ini file, the Loaded Configuration File has it pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.ini but I don't see it there.