# PHP connection with SQL Server using sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using `sqlsrv_connect` on a PHP file, here´s my code:

```
<?php
        $serverName = "ANDIEPC"; //serverName\instanceName
        $db = "Products_Test";

        // Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
        // The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>**'Products_Test'**);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if( $conn ) {
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
        }else{
            echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
?>
```

I login to this DB using Windows Authentication and it is just a test database I made on my computer. I get the following error:

> Connection could not be established.
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png) => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png) => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png) => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Products_Test" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Products_Test" requested by the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png) => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png) => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Products_Test" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "Products_Test" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )

Once I go to SQL Server LOGs, I find this:
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwfSb.png)

I found that this state: 38 means:

> Could not find database requested by user.".

So, if on my code , I remove the database name or even enter "master" (on the highlighted part above) it gives me a successful connection message. But for any other database it keeps returning the error. And yes, the database I am referring to does exist on my server. Any ideas why it cannot find any other database but the master?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38773083/4323201

Comment: I'd be somewhat concerned that it's trying to use `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`... this seems like it's connecting from a misconfigured web server with far too much access.

Comment: Under what Windows login is the PHP code being executed?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is just a test I am making on my computer by using xampp.

Comment: @Charlieface using my login which, since it is a test on my personal computer, I am admin.

Comment: @RyanNerd thank you very much, that answer made it :)